# Adding a # in a column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to add a pound sign (#) to a string in a SQL table.

I have a stored procedure that creates a table. Once that table is created, I need to update on field to add E# before the existing string.

I've tried this:

```
DECLARE @intro VARCHAR = 'E[#]'
UPDATE [regKioskdb].[dbo].[MOBapptTest]
SET emrID =(@intro + emrID)
```

This adds an E before the existing string, but not the #. Is there another way to do this?

We are using this table as a look up for when someone scans a card. The card is formatted at E#HubLive0000000. We tried using javascript to remove the E# from the input, but didn't have any luck when scanned.

Scenario: User scans card on webpage at kiosk. Webpage queries the database - looking for the number from the card scan. If it finds the number, it returns a message on the webpage. Since I'm not having luck adding the E# in the table I created, every scan shows up as "not found" even if the account number is in the database (without the E#).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Stop saying `VARCHAR` and specify the size, like `VARCHAR(32)`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). Debugging 101: `PRINT @intro;` would have yielded that the value was truncated before ever trying to update the table...

Comment: Indeed. `varchar` for  `"E[#]"`  is just `E` as it's actually varchar(1). You should put it as an answer @Aaron because it's the actual cause.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I'm in a trial by fire situation, and learning as I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
UPDATE [regKioskdb].[dbo].[MOBapptTest]
SET emrID = 'E' + CHAR(35) + emrId
```

(Obviously test it first)

Comment: This doesn't help if `E#` comes from a variable or parameter, perhaps submitted by an end user. It also assumes that the character itself is the problem, when that's not the issue at all.

Comment: Are you sure it even makes it to the stored procedure in its proper form, then? Have you done something like `SELECT @intro`?

Comment: CHAR(35) worked perfectly. I should have been clear, in the stored procedure I'm pulling the account number from another table in the database. The input from the card scanner/website is just used to match the person scanning the card to their account in the database.

Comment: @user1623347 that is ***NOT*** the fix. `DECLARE @into VARCHAR = 'E' + CHAR(35); PRINT @intro;` <-- does that fix it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not sure I'm doing the PRINT correctly. When I changed my code to this and ran the stored procedure, the pound sign didn't show up. I changed it to    `DECLARE @intro VARCHAR(2) = 'E' + CHAR(35)` and it worked. Just curious, if I get the same result with the code from @Ruslan - what's the benefit of using the `DECLARE` statement over his code?

Comment: @user1623347 Whether you use `CHAR(35)` or `#` is immaterial - if you declare as `VARCHAR` with no length, you're going to have truncation. If you're always going to prefix the string with `E#` then there is no benefit to using a variable. I assumed that (a) you simplified the code, and maybe this was a parameter and (b) that it wouldn't always be `E#`.